# Display value of selected array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, textbox, listbox

I have a CSV file that is formatted as (name,number) on each line.

I'm creating an app that loads all names, index(0), into a listbox at form-load and when a name is selected the number, `index(1)`, is displayed in a `.textbox`.

I start by filling an array and displaying `index(0)` in the box. No Prob. But when the selected text changes I have problems. If you cant tell I'm new to VB. If I could assign a var to the selected text I could use a while loop but I'm not sure how to assign that. Is there a better way to go about this? Below is my source. Any help would be great.

```
Public Class Form1

Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("MembershipPhone.txt")
        Dim myData = line.Split(","c)
        Dim mName = myData(0)
        Dim mPhone = myData(1)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(mName)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("MembershipPhone.txt")
        Dim query = line.Split(","c)
        Dim mName = query(0)
        Dim mPhone = query(1)
        TextBox2.Text = mPhone
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: the `dim x = 1` style suggests that this ain't vbscript or VBA my friend... I suggest you remove those tags. Also, after the form loads you have immediately lost all the phone numbers. I suggest you read up on dictionaries or associative arrays

Comment: Im learning C++ and Python right now too so ive found it easy to mixup my syntax. I'm reading up on that now. I did however make it work:

Comment: `Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        For Each line As String In ""IO.File.ReadAllLines("MembershipPhone.txt")
            Dim query = line.Split(","c)
            Dim mName = query(0)
            Dim mPhone = query(1)
            If ListBox1.SelectedItem = mName Then
                TextBox1.Text = mName
                TextBox2.Text = mPhone
            End If
        Next
    End Sub""`